# How to make regular expression match a required text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a regular expression that I have written,

```
regex = "car\S*\s*(\w+\s+){1,2}\s*\S*wash"
```

This regex match the texts such as (i.e., one or two words between "car" and "wash"),

```
"car. was good ?wash"
"car wash"
"car will never wash"
```

But I want the above regex to also match these variation of texts,

```
texts = [
"Car, not ... (?!) wash",   # (i.e., this should match because only one words between car and wash but has any number punctuations in between)
"Car never:)... $@@! with wash", # (i.e., this also should match because only two words between car and wash but has any more punctuations in between)
"Car, was never wash",
"Car...:) things, not wash"]
```

But the regex I have written is failing? How can I modify the regex I wrote to make it match all the above texts given,

```
import re

# Define the regular expression
regex = "car\S*\s*(\w+\s+){1,2}\s*\S*wash"

# Use the re.search() function to find a match
match = re.search(regex, "Car, not ... (?!) wash", flags=re.I)

# Check if a match was found
if match:
    print("Match found: ", match.group(0))
else:
    print("No match found")
```

In short, I have to match any text that start with "car" and end with "wash" but with conditions.

- It can have only 1 to 2 words in between car and wash. The regex I
  wrote take care of that issue.
- Along with those N words, it can have
  any number of punctuation's or spaces between them.

Comment: If I understand the requirement right ("match anything that starts with car and ends with wash"), `.*` will match 0 or more of any character, so your entire thing can be `car.*wash`. If the matching is more complicated than that, you'll have to explain more clearly what you want to match.

Comment: @Kaia Added more info in the question

Comment: "The regex I have take care of 1 to 6 words." Not true; `{1,2}` does not. "This regex match the texts such as (...) car wash." Not true; "car wash" does not match. Please be consistent in your question and comments, to make the question answerable.

Comment: If you find the regex too restrictive, you could start with replacing `\w` with `\S`, and replacing `{1,2}` with `{1,6}`. On the other hand, the regex is also too permissive; it matches e.g. "Scare has been sqwashed." When writing test cases, also think about text that must _not_ match.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question so people can understand better. I am clear on {1,2} or {1,6} I can change it based on my requirement but what I am having trouble is my second condition in my question. can you check it once?

Comment: @RuudHelderman For example, I have this text `"Car, not ... (?!) wash"`, here I have only one word which is not and has quite a few punctuations. It satisfied my two conditions so I want this to get matched. But let's say the text is something like this `car not ... with you wash`, it should fail because it has more than 2 words

Comment: "It can have any number of punctuation's or spaces between them." Please be specific; how would you define punctuation? According to you, how many words is "info@google.com"? How many words is "2.4 Children" or "2.4 GHz Wi-Fi"?

Comment: @RuudHelderman `info@google.com` is one word, `2.4 children` is two words, `2.4 GHz Wi-Fi` is three words. Let's say if there is something like this `Car !@! with never wash` this is treated as two words between car and wash. If there's something like `car 121@ with @#$% never wash`, this is treated as three words between car and wash because `@#$%` is treated as punctuation and should be ignored because there is not English alphabets in that.

Comment: What about leading and trailing whitespace, punctuation, words? Are " Car to wash " and "@Car to wash!!!" and "The car should wash itself" allowed? I'm asking because right now, those _do_ match, but they were never mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RuudHelderman That's fine, All those three texts can be matched. No issues with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of your question plus additional comments, I am defining the following rules.

1. A word is a sequence of one or more non-whitespace characters, at least one of which must be a letter, digit or underscore (the latter as it is part of the character class `\w`).
2. Words are separated by at least one whitespace character, mixed with zero or more 'punctuation' characters (i.e. anything but letter/digit/underscore).

There is some ambiguity in my definition; punctuation between a letter and a space could be considered part of the word (rule #1) or part of the separation between words (rule #2).
But when counting words, that makes no difference.

From there, I can build two subpatterns.

- `\S*\w\S*` - a word has at least one word character, and no whitespace
- `\W*\s\W*` - a separator has at least one whitespace character, and no word character

Chaining the subpatterns:

```
\bcar\W*\s\W*(\S*\w\S*\W*\s\W*){1,2}wash\b
```

Notice the word boundaries `\b` on either side, to prevent "scar" and "washing" to be mistaken for "car" and "wash".

This matches all of these texts:

```
car. was good ?wash            # 2 words and punctuation between car and wash
car will never wash            # 2 words
Car, not ... (?!) wash         # 1 word
Car never:)... $@@! with wash  # 2 words
Car, was never wash            # 2 words
Car...:) things, not wash      # 2 words
```

An alternate approach would be to first strip all punctuation from the string, and then match against `\bcar\s+(\S+\s+){1,2}wash\b`